# Python: change format for all elements in a list of strings

Tags: python, string

I have a list of strings:

```
a = ['[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]',
     '[2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]',
     '[3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]',
     '[4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0]',
     '[5.0, 5.0, 5.0]', 
     '[1.0]'
    ]
```

When I use the code as below, the format for every element in the list is string, not the int.

```
a= tuple(a.reshape(1,-1)[0])
```

What I need to do is change the format for all elements. Such as

```
a[1][2] = 2
```

However, in my code:

```
a[1][2] = '.'
```

Comment: `a` is a list of strings.

Answer (score 4):

`a` is a list of strings. I don't know where you got it from, but as far as I understand your question you want it to be a list of lists which contain numbers. This might be a use case for the `eval` function.

```
>>> a
['[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]', '[2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]', '[3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]', '[4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0]', '[5.0, 5.0, 5.0]', '[1.0]']
>>> a = [eval(x) for x in a]
>>> a
[[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0], [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0], [4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0], [5.0, 5.0, 5.0], [1.0]]
>>> a[1][2]
2.0
```

If you do not want to use `eval`, I would suggest

```
a = [[float(x) for x in liststring[1:-1].split(',')] for liststring in a]
```

Comment: haha, almost at the exact same time. Yeah, I feel the same, `eval` makes me feel uneasy, but I don't think this is going to be used to execute code dynamically

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
>>> a =['[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]', '[2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]','[3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]','[4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0]','[5.0, 5.0, 5.0]','[1.0]']
>>> a
['[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]', '[2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]', '[3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]', '[4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0]', '[5.0, 5.0, 5.0]', '[1.0]']
>>> a2 = [eval(l) for l in a]
>>> a2[1][2]
2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `a` is a list of strings, not a list of lists. It should be:

```
a = [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
[2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0],
[3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0],
[4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0],
[5.0, 5.0, 5.0],
[1.0]]
```

EDIT -- AN ACTUAL ANSWER:

Okay I realize this is an old problem for you now, but I just ran across another solution that does not use eval() (and thus avoids the security issues). Your list of strings `a` can be decoded using the json module and then turned into a new list of lists:

```
import json

def decodeList(list_of_strings):
    newList = list()
    for i in list_of_strings:
         newList.append(json.loads(i))
    return newList

a = decodeList(a)

print a[1][2]

# outputs 2.0
```

EDIT AGAIN:

Haha I just read through the rest of the answers and noticed someone already offered this one! Sigh. Nevermind.

Comment: Bro, I know what you mean. However, my case is a list of list. I want to find any element as an int. in my list, not a string

Comment: Ah, sorry misunderstood the issue. @timgeb looks like a working answer then!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [JSON](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module; it is made specifically for these kinds of jobs. I made an example below. It converts all the items of list a (which are strings originally) into lists of floats. If you want to convert them to ints, just iterate through the nested lists and make blahblah = int(blahblah) (just be careful that you don't put something into the list that can't be converted into an integer, such as "s").

```
from json import loads

a = ['[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]',
 '[2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]',
 '[3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]',
 '[4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0]',
 '[5.0, 5.0, 5.0]', 
 '[1.0]'
]

for nestlist in range(len(a)):
    a[nestlist] = loads(a[nestlist])

print a
```

Hope this helps!
Palmer :)